# Promote Row 1 as Column Heading - Spark DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I got below Spark Data Frame.

[image]

I want to promote Row 1 as column Headings and the new spark DataFrame should be

[image]

I know this can be done in pandas easily as:

```
new_header =  pandaDF.iloc[0]
pandaDF = pandaDF[1:]
pandaDF.columns = new_header
```

**But** doesn't want to convert into Pandas DF as have to persist this into to Database, wherein have to convert back pandas DF to Spark DF and then register as table and then write to db.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **`.toDF`** and **`filter`** our the column values.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample dataframe
df.show()
#+----------+------------+----------+
#|    prop_0|      prop_1|    prop_2|
#+----------+------------+----------+
#|station_id|station_name|sample_num|
#|       101|  Station101| Sample101|
#|       102|  Station102| Sample102|
#+----------+------------+----------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

cols=sc.parallelize(cols).map(lambda x:x).collect()

df.toDF(*cols).filter(~col("station_id").isin(*cols)).show()
#+----------+------------+----------+
#|station_id|station_name|sample_num|
#+----------+------------+----------+
#|       101|  Station101| Sample101|
#|       102|  Station102| Sample102|
#+----------+------------+----------+
```